# Eclipse reference chooser; no ID Label

Tags: android, eclipse, reference, eclipse-indigo

When I tried to set attiburites of layout in Eclipse Indigo 3.7, reference chooser which had ID label in eclipse 3.6 doesn't show up (But drawable,layout and string options are still there). So I have to put ids manually.

Is there some kind of fix or option for this. I generally use relative layout so ID label at reference chooser somehow important to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete xml files inside values,layout and drawable folder,before that copy that file in some other location in your drive.After that delete the values,layout and drawable folder from your application,now create a folder to that name again and copy all xml files from drive to your apllication.I am sure that you cant get warning or error.